Armature problem
Here I fail to fold my box with the armature as seen :



I simply don't get it why it does this because I used to do the same operation to fold my box and it wouldn't do what it does now, so my question is how to solve this issue (which usually doesn't happen) and how do I "prevent" this bug from randomly happening (Blender version 4.1.1)
here is another problem (where the upper part would randomly work this time) :


this time the upper part is correctly flipping (same build order as above but this time it worked) but the blue part (the inside part of the box) appears outside the green part when i flip the upper part
Edit :


The vertices of the top of your box must assigned to a wrong vertex groups, select them and remove from this group, if it doesn't work please share your file

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

@moonboots I added the file
& how to remove vertexs from a group ?

As you see if you select one of these vertices, it is assigned to 2 groups, Bone and Bone.001, but it should not be assigned to Bone as it will let the bone called Bone control it as well:

So select the 2 vertices, select the vertex group called Bone and click on Remove:


it worked, merci moonboots!
